# What are the generic type variables on the Typescript ThunkAction type in redux-thunk

Tags: typescript, redux-thunk

Could anyone help me understand this type -maybe with a simple example- and how to use it correctly since I don't understand what this go between the < >? I just need to make a request to an API.

Answer (score 1):

`ThunkAction` is a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), meaning that the specific type of any individual `ThunkAction` depends on the variables inside of the `<>`.

This section of [the docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.d.ts) explains the meaning of each variable:

```
/**
 * A "thunk" action (a callback function that can be dispatched to the Redux
 * store.)
 *
 * Also known as the "thunk inner function", when used with the typical pattern
 * of an action creator function that returns a thunk action.
 *
 * @template TReturnType The return type of the thunk's inner function
 * @template TState The redux state
 * @template TExtraThunkARg Optional extra argument passed to the inner function
 * (if specified when setting up the Thunk middleware)
 * @template TBasicAction The (non-thunk) actions that can be dispatched.
 */
export type ThunkAction<
  TReturnType,
  TState,
  TExtraThunkArg,
  TBasicAction extends Action
> = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<TState, TExtraThunkArg, TBasicAction>,
  getState: () => TState,
  extraArgument: TExtraThunkArg,
) => TReturnType;
```

You shouldn't need to explicitly type all four of those variables.  In fact you should need to use `ThunkAction` at all.  It just defines a function with a particular signature. So when you create your own thunk functions, you just need to type your function arguments (`dispatch`, `getState`, `extraArguments`), and the rest will be inferred.

You can get the specific dispatch type for your store like this:

```
type MyDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

But it defaults to `Dispatch` which should be fine for most cases.

```
function makeASandwichWithSecretSauce(forPerson: string ) {
  return function(dispatch: Dispatch) {
    return fetchSecretSauce().then(
      (sauce) => dispatch(makeASandwich(forPerson, sauce)),
      (error) => dispatch(apologize('The Sandwich Shop', forPerson, error)),
    );
  };
}
```